# gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf on Yocto

Tags: linux, gcc, yocto

I just installed a hardfloat toolchain using the following command on my Ubuntu

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

I want to compile my packages on Yocto using the hardfloat toolchain. So I add the following lines to `conf/local.conf`

```
TUNE_FEATURES ?= "armv7athf-neon"
SDK_PATH="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
TARGET_SYS = "arm-linux-gnueabihf"
PATH +=":${SDK_PATH}/bin"
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--target=$TARGET_SYS --host=$TARGET_SYS --build=i686-linux --with-libtool-sysroot=$SYSROOT"
CPPFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS"
CXXFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$SYSROOT"
```

But after compiling command `bitbake gmp` I received this ERROR:

```
| configure: error: --target is not appropriate for GMP
| Use --build=CPU-VENDOR-OS if you need to specify your CPU and/or system
| explicitly.  Use --host if cross-compiling (see "Installing GMP" in the
| manual for more on this).
```

on `virtual:native:/home/dev/yocto/poky-daisy/meta/recipes-support/gmp/gmp_5.1.1.bb, do_configure`

**It should be note that before any change on `conf/local.conf` every things worked properly**

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, when try compile arm-linux-gnueabihf

edit meta/recipes-support/gmp/gmp.inc and add

```
PACKAGECONFIG[host] = "--host=${HOST_SYS},--host=${TARGET_SYS},host"
EXTRA_OECONF += " --disable-assembly"
```

Ist happened because gmt.inc use autotools
/meta/classes/autotools.bbclass and variable CONFIGUREOPTS in autotools.bbclass contains --host=${HOST_SYS}